# Why couldn't I use XML onClick attribute for Event Handling?

Tags: android

I am writing a simple computing machine which basically shows in the text view the sum of 2 numbers I entered in two edit text. Theoretically, it should be right, but in my case I feel like something went wrong, perhaps about missing components. At first, I thought the problem had come from the edit text but later I changed it and nothing new happened. That makes me doubt about the use of onClick attribute. The program automatically stops when I pressed the button

Specifically, I have my java code

```
package com.example.computing_machine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Computing_Machine extends Activity {
private TextView text;

protected void onCreate(Bundle x) {
    super.onCreate(x);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_computing_machine);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
}

public void sum(View v) {
/*  EditText e1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText e2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    int a  = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText() + "");
    int b  = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText() + ""); */

    text.setText(5);
}
}
```

And this is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.computing_machine.Computing_Machine" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/number1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/number2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" > 

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" 
    android:onClick="sum"/>
```

Comment: You said the app stops. Could you post the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Code:**

```
int a  = Integer.parseInt(""+e1.getText().toString());
int b  = Integer.parseInt(""+e2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I must be more careful about arguments, but I wonder would it be still good if I used "0" + e1.getText() only, I think we pretty much have a string at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
text.setText("" + 5);
```

`setText` takes a string as its argument. You are passing an `int`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my big, big error. You also give me a very succinct way to handle it